# How to use parameter as a filter in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have one Field called as 'Empl Flag' having values All and Null , I am using this field as a Filter with below calculation called as 'Exclude Employees'.

```
Case [Empl Flag] 
when NULL then "Yes"
else "No"
END
```

Filter is working fine. Now, I have created one parameter called as 'Exclude Employeees?' having 3 string values - Yes, No, Employees.

How do I use this parameter as a Filter to get the same values while filtering with `Empl Flag`

Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output when parameter is equal to yes, no and employees?

Comment: when yes- It should select all nulls, when No - It should select All Employees , when Employees - It should select Nulls + All Employees. Always, No must be greater than Yes .

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can make the filter work.

Create a Calculated field like

```
if Exclude Employees (parameter) == "Employees" then TRUE else Exclude Employees (calculated field)== Exclude Employees (parameter) end
```

and drag and drop this field in the filters pane by choosing TRUE. That should do it

Comment: I tried this, but not getting actual result. When I am selecting Employees - nothing is coming on screen (It should result No+ Yes condition). I am getting the result of Yes for and vice-versa.

Comment: Yeah, so I wasn't sure what output you wanted when Employees is selected so didn't use that. Please try the updated solution now